# See Windows shared folder in Android

Tags: sync, cifs

I have shared a folder named `myfolder` in Windows, the computer name is `MYPC`.

I installed FolderSync on Android and I would like to connect to this shared folder via SMB.

**What's the relevant share address with `smb:...` ?**

```
smb://MYPC/myfolder
```

or

```
smb:///MYPC/myfolder
```

or

```
smb:\\\MYPC\myfolder
```

I tried all these options, but it did not work.

Comment: Can you add the Play Store link to the app? There seems to be many apps with that name, causing ambiguity.

Answer (score 1):

***STEPS to create a SMB account in [FolderSync](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=dk.tacit.android.foldersync.lite):***

1. Open the app, go to options and select 'Account'
2. Select 'Add Account' ('+' symbol), click 'SMB/CIFS'.
3. Enter a name.
4. *Server Address*: enter the local IP address of the Windows Computer where sharing is enabled.

Format: `smb://local_ip`

For example, `smb://192.168.0.3`

(You can easily find your computer's local IP by `ipconfig` command in Command Prompt)

5. Then enter the login credentials of computer if Windows Sharing is password-protected, or use Anonymous login if password-protection is switched off..

Now you're ready to create the syncs you need.

---

Alternatively, you can also use **[ES File Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop).**

Goto Options(3lines at top left)-> Network-> LAN.

Search for devices there, or add it if you know the correct address..

Comment: Thanks! I'd like to use FolderSync... (of ES File Explorer does sync as well?) Oh we just discussed this morning on Xda forum about your wondefffffful UMS enabler ! :)

Comment: Lol, nice to hear :) BTW, I'll add the steps for the foldersync app after I install and use it

Answer (score 0):

Solution : in FolderSync app, one should not write the shared folder in the URL, but just the IP :

```
smb://<ip address or hostname>
```